# THREE.js JSONLoader callback

Tags: json, callback, geometry, three.js, loader

In THREE.js, if I have multiple calls to the JSONLoader to load multiple objects like this (simplified example):

```
function init() {    
  var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();    
  loader.load("mesh1.js", createScene);    
  loader.load("mesh2.js", createScene);
}    

function createScene( geometry ) {    
  if (geometry.filename == "mesh1.js") {    
    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh1 );    
  } else if (geometry.filename == "mesh2.js") {    
    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh2 );
  }
}
```

How can I determine which mesh has been returned on callback, especially when they frequently arrive out of order?

I'm trying to handle multiple returned meshes with a single generic callback function. Is there some property in the returned geometry that indicates the original filename that I can test against?

Or perhaps there's a more elegant way? Perhaps creating a new THREE.JSONLoader object for each call would help the callback function determine which mesh has arrived?

I appreciate any help/ideas! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well there is a more generic way then what WestLangley proposes.

```
loader.load( "mesh1.js", meshloader("mesh1.js")); 
loader.load( "mesh2.js", meshloader("mesh2.js"));
```

then

```
function meshloader(fileName){
    return function(geometry){
        ...
    }
}
```

This way, you can add a identifier on each loaded file.

Comment: fantastic... I was able to get this working. I would never have thought to return a function within a function. I'm really curious on what exactly is going on here... Can you please explain a little on how/why this works or point me in the direction of some documentation?

Comment: @Dev This is what's called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). When `meshloader("mesh1.js")` is passed as an argument, it is directly executed (due to the presence of parentheses). When executed, it returns another function. So it's exactly as if you passed the anonymous function `function(geometry){...}` as an argument, excepted that this anonymous function will be executed as a callback in a context where the variable `fileName` is defined and has the value `"mesh1.js"`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
loader.load( "mesh1.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, 1 ) } ); 
loader.load( "mesh2.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, 2 ) } );
```

Then,

```
function createScene( geometry, id ) {
 ...
}
```

The `id` can be the mesh name if you prefer that.

Comment: Ah, I've been down this path.. sure it works with a constant, like "1" or "2" but the problem seems to be that when "1" and "2" are replaced with a variable, say "x", the variable gets evaluated only *after* the callback returns. I can't seem to find a way to pass along a variable to createScene with a value determined before loader.load is called... make sense? scope problem? temporal problem?

Comment: This is an answer to your question. You are now asking a different question. Perhaps you can post a new issue.