# Attempting to import blender json model into three.js, getting a 'length' error

Tags: json, three.js, blender

I'm attempting to use a JSON 3D model from Blender, and having it to where it shifts slightly based on mouse/touch movement on the screen.

I'm getting an error of "cannot read property "Length" of undefined, and I'm not finding good documentation of how to load models from Blender into three.js anywhere.

This is my code.

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( 'js/Neuron.json', );
```

https://pastebin.com/wD59mGBu

Any help or even someone pointing me to an online resource to demonstrate a result would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried it without the comma after your json file? also check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997234/three-js-jsonloader-callback?rq=1
it seems like you need a callback for after the file has loaded to add it to your scene

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly load a Json File in Threejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930473/how-to-properly-load-a-json-file-in-threejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the Json file itself; it was exported without "scene" being chosen as the option. Doing that and setting the importer worked.